# Android, SQL: how to find out if existing column has a value?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am pretty new to Android and stackoverflow and this is my first problem...I hope you can help me.

I have to create an app, on basis of a sqlite db, which has columns like id, category.... and steps. The steps columns are from 1 to 16 max and are named step1 to step16, but not all entries have all steps filled.
So e.g. the first record has only step1 to step6 filled with some string values, the second record might have step1 to step10 and so on.
Now I try to find out the maximum steps which actually have a value in it...and it always crashes with

```
12-20 15:45:41.038: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1243): Shutting down VM
12-20 15:45:41.038: WARN/dalvikvm(1243): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-20 15:45:41.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
12-20 15:45:41.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lochmann.zaubertricks/de.lochmann.zaubertricks.TrickExplanation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

I already tried lots of things, at the moment I am stuck here:

```
public int getMaxSteps(int id) {
    int step=1;
    String query="SELECT step"+Integer.toString(step)+" FROM "+DB_NAME+" WHERE _id="+id;
    Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
    while(myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        if (myCursor.getString(0)!=null) {
            step++;
        query="SELECT step"+Integer.toString(step)+" FROM "+DB_NAME+" WHERE _id="+id;
            myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query,null);
        }
    }
    return step;
}
```

Basically I'm looking for the column with name step+x, if it exists and is not empty I increase step and start again. Works, but it doesn't stop at myCursor.getString(0)!=null. I put try catch blocks as well, but to no avail.
Any suggestions, or any other way to accomplish what I am looking for? Chances are I miss some basic principle...

So the record might look like:

```
ID Name Description Step1 Step2 Step3 Step4 Step5 Step6 Step7 ... Step16
1  Test Foo         test  test  test  test  test  test  -         -
```

And the getMaxSteps(1) method should return a 6 in our case, as this is the last cell with a value.

And what might be that uncaught exception the log talks about?

p.s: I know it's a very bad database design, it's not mine, I just have to work with it.

Pretty long first post, I hope you can help me :)

Greetings Martin

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you do a query on a non-existing column, you are going to get a database exception.  I'm not sure why you aren't getting a proper stack dump in your log however. As soon as you do a query with a column that doesn't exist, it will throw.  Is that what you expect?

What I would do is do a `select *` query and then look at the columns returned.  Maybe something like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_NAME + " WHERE _id=" + id;
Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
if (! myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
   // no results
   return 0;
}
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("step" + i);
    if (index < 0) {
         return i - 1;
    }
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Something is wrong and we'll be careful");
```

This will save you from your multiple queries which is much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `mycursor` is `null` when your query pulls back `null` as the value of step 7?

Comment: If not i would check that the underlying datastructure that `getString(int)` looks up has been initialised when the return data is `null`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The cursor wasn't null, it's the cursor.getstring() that's null. See my own reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input folks, I finally managed to solve the problem, and it was easier than expected, I just had to check if the returned string is null or not.

Code:

```
public int getMaxSteps(int id) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_NAME + " WHERE _id=" + id;
    Cursor myCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (!myCursor.moveToFirst()) return -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <16; i++) {
        if (myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("step" + Integer.toString(i)))==null) { return i - 1; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again, I'm pretty sure I'll need some more advice soon :)